# Negative Lookahead not working as expected

Tags: regex

I want to match all the numbers not followed by a `Doller`:

```
100Dollar
1000Dollar
100Yuan
1000Yuan
```

the regex:

```
\d+(?!Dollar)
```

But the result is weird:

[image: img]

Live example:

https://regexr.com/3ko0t

Comment: What about using a positive lookahead to ensure what follows is not a digit: [`\d+(?=\D)(?!Dollar)`](https://regex101.com/r/LakTVb/1) or [`\d+(?!\d)(?!Dollar)`](https://regex101.com/r/LakTVb/2)?

Comment: Could you add the language you are using please? Solutions using possessive quantifiers or atomic groups will not work in some...

Comment: I'm just testing regex in a web tool, it's uses js engine by default.

Comment: A regex with atomic group - `(?>\d+)(?!Dollar)` / possessive quantifier - `\d++(?!Dollar)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a digit class to the negative lookahead to assure that you match till the then of a number:

```
\d+(?!Dollar|\d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/3boUGL/2)

Comment: No need to group inside the lookahead. Removing the group improves performance.

Answer (score 2):

**Regex**: [`(?!\d+Dollar)\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/R5jKPY/1)

Details:

- `(?!)` Negative Lookahead
- `\d` Matches a digit (equal to `[0-9]`)
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times

Comment: This is good, but please add an explanation for why this works and the OP's doesn't.

Comment: It really works, but i don't think it's a neat solution (logically). `\d+(?!Dollar|\d)` would be better I think?